# Ressource returns null when more than one language is in the project

Tags: uwp

I have an Windows UWP Project who targets FCU with a .net standard 2.0 project for code sharing between platforms. In that project I have a resource file called "Strings.resx" and as long as I only have one of these it is working as expected. But when I add a file "Strings.de.resx" for the german translations `Strings.[MyString]` will only return null.

I already tried running the custom tool. But it doens't work. As soon as I remove the second file and run custom tool it works again.

It also doesn't matter it the requested string is in the new resource file or not. The error occurs in both occations.

I also made a small example. You can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/NPadrutt/ResourceTest

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ressource returns null when more than one language is in the project

This is caused by that you didn't designate your application's default culture. This is the culture whose resources are used if no localized resources for a particular culture can be found.  Since you have more than one language, if you didn't designate the default culture, the resource will not know which one should use so return null.

Right click your class library project which contains the `.resx` files, click **`Package`** and select  the appropriate language/culture in the **Neutral language** list.

[image]

More details please reference [Resource Files in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps#resource-files-in-visual-studio).